# Regex for validating and sanitizing all english and non-english unicode alphabet characters in PHP

Tags: php, regex

While there have been many questions regarding the non-english characters regex issue I have not been able to find a working answer. Moreover, there does not seem to be any simple PHP library which would help me to filter non-english input.

Could you please suggest me a regular expression which would allow

1. all english alphabet characters (abc...)
2. all non-english alphabet characters (šýüčá...)
3. spaces
4. case insensitive

in validation as well as sanitization. Essentially, I want either preg_match to return false when the input contains anything else than the 4 points above or preg_replace to get rid of everything except these 4 categories.

I was able to create
`'/^((\p{L}\p{M}*)|(\p{Cc})|(\p{Z}))+$/ui'` from http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html. This regular expression works well when validating input but not when sanitizing it.

EDIT:

User enters 'český [jazyk]' as an input. Using `'/^[\p{L}\p{Zs}]+$/u'` in preg_match, the script determines that the string contains unallowed characters (in this case '[' and ']'). Next I would like to use preg_replace, to delete those unwanted characters. What regular expression should I pass into preg_replace to match all characters that are not specified by the regular expression stated above?

Comment: First, you don't know the context. Second, trying to allow multinational alphpabet does not seem like a discrimination to me.

Comment: Define "sanitizing".

Comment: In this context, it is simply an effort to eliminate any characters that would compromise the security of my site.

Comment: How in the world could a simple Latin letter like **č** possibly “compromise the security of your site”?  This sounds like a different bug, and one wholly of your own making, not one of the data.  Please explain exactly what you mean.  You will notice that Stack Overflow allows us to use **č** with wild abandon without “compromising the security of their site”.  What is it that you are doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the question again. I was searching for a regular expression that would allow letters like Czech čřšž not eliminate them.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! In that case, you do still have to do more than you have there.  You need to include grapheme extender code points (read: combining marks), too. So not just `\pL` but `(?=\pL)\X` for the entire grapheme whose grapheme base is a letter.  Otherwise it will strip combining characters inappropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need is a character class like:

```
^[\p{L}\p{Zs}]+$
```

It means: The whole string (or line, with `(?m)` option) can only contain Unicode letters or spaces.

Have a look at the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qP5nU8/2).

```
$re = "/^[\\p{L}\\p{Zs}]+$/um"; 
$str = "all english alphabet characters (abc...)\nall non-english alphabet characters (šýüčá...)\nspace s\nšýüčá šýüčá šýüčá ddd\nšýüčá eee 4\ncase insensitive"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

To remove all symbols that are not Unicode letters or spaces, use this code:

```
$re = "/[^\\p{L}\\p{Zs}]+/u"; 
$str = "český [jazyk]"; 
echo preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

The output of the [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMX0h5bm9oTWU1Qjg):

```
český jazyk
```

Comment: Works like a charm when validating, thank you. However, when I plug it into preg_replace (preg_replace($expr, '', $input)), it deletes the whole input when there are only english alphabet characters ('aa' => '', 'ač' => 'ač'). Do I need to modify the expression when I want to sanitize an input string?

Comment: I don't understand preg_replace very much but it should propably find all characters that are not in your regex and replace them with nothing. At least that's the way I need it to work.

Comment: Can you please check the code at http://goo.gl/hgXaAe ? I am not sure what you want to do. `[\W\P{Zs}]+` will match all non-English letters and non-numbers and non-`_`, and non-spaces. So, all English letters, numbers, `_` and spaces will remain after `preg_replace`.

Comment: I actually want english and non-english alphabet letters to stay, as I stated in my question. I originally thought I can use preg_replace to whitelist the characters I want to allow in the input but I could just blacklist everything I don't want. 

What I am trying to do is to allow things like: 'Český jazyk' but delete characters that could be used for XSS, for instance '<>'.

The site you linked unfortunatelly does not work for me.

Comment: @Webster: I am afraid that makes your question "too broad". Please check http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42498/which-is-the-best-way-to-sanitize-user-input-in-php. for sanitization details in PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand all the implications of the word sanitize. I added a concrete example to my question. I hope it makes the question clearer.

Comment: This statement makes so sense whatsoever. The letters A and Z are Unicode letters.

Comment: My previous comment contained a remnant that I did not want to post, sorry. I should have posted this: "To remove the characters other than Unicode letters and spaces, you need to remove the anchors and negate the character class: `[^\p{L}\p{Zs}]+`".